# How to compress GIF image programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, gif, image-compression

I want to compress large sized GIF image file(s) before sending them to the server for my chatting application (WhatsApp like feature).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A GIF is already compressed, by definition. Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF): "GIF images are compressed using the Lempel–Ziv–Welch (LZW) lossless data compression technique to reduce the file size without degrading the visual quality".

Comment: @CommonsWare- I tested for WhatsApp where I sent a gif file (size:5.93MB) and on receiver end I found the file size is 163KB with mp4 format but they present that as gif image. I need reduced size. How can I do this?

Comment: The only thing that anyone can tell you, in the abstract, is to reduce the resolution of the image. Beyond that, it will depend a lot on the nature of the input. For example, lossy compression (e.g., JPEG, MP4) works well for photographic content and works poorly for line art.

Comment: Lossy compression will be OK for my purpose but I need reduced size of inputted GIF as output GIF format.

Comment: @Zia where you able to solve it?